# How did the engineer enter the locked ship?

Tags: plot-explanation, prometheus

During the last scene in Prometheus, how did the Engineer enter the ship after Dr.Shaw had locked the doors?

Comment: for me the biggest inconsistency from the original Alien movie was that the alien emerged from the engineer on board the prometheus .. in the original they find him in his ship in the control seat with the open rib cage

Comment: "How did the Engineer enter the ship?" Was there not an explosion and the on-board computer system message telling Dr. Shaw that the hull had been breached? I can't remember this one too clearly, but I'm sure that there was.

Answer (score 12):

This question has been edited a bunch of times. I'll try and break it down:

> During the last scene in Prometheus, how did the Engineer enter the ship after Dr.Shaw had locked the doors?

Brute force I guess - he was also able to rip an android's head off. This may be something to come in a future director's cut, as I think [a few minutes of fight scene were edited-out](http://collider.com/ridley-scott-prometheus-deleted-scenes-interview/172202/) between the Engineer arriving at the pod and Shaw opening the inner door to the squid-thing (possibly to avoid an R/18 rating).

I'm also not sure that she actually locked the external doors, just closed the air-lock door.

> And how come the engineer came without the mask?

Early on they state that the atmosphere is almost breathable, but with toxic levels of CO2. maybe the Engineer has a higher tolerance to CO2, or maybe he could hold his breath for the fairly short walk from the crashed ship to the life-pod.

> Also, what is that floating ball device which creates holographic maps from in the engineers ship?

Fifield (the geologist) brought the floating red balls in order to map the location - it sounds like they are standard kit for mapping caves or similar. Fifield refers to them has his 'pups'. They create the holographic map of the Engineer's pyramid on-board the Prometheus.

> (and how come it floats)?

Not a clue. They have faster than light travel, almost-human androids and suspended animation. I figure they have some advanced space tech in there.

> and what is that map like shown in the engineers ship ?

The map inside the Engineer's ship appears to be some kind of holographic [orrery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orrery), though I don't think it maps to just one system or to scale. I'm not sure whether that includes some kind of Kinect-like gesture interface or whether David just appears to touch the map of the Earth.

Comment: Man, from your quotes it seems we can already be pretty lucky with the current version of the question ;)

Comment: Other than the floating bit (and maybe being that small), those pups pretty much [exist already](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXlqv_k4P8Q).

Comment: @NickT That's awesome! I want it on my car :-)